# List Box with BindingSource containing objects not showing displayName C#

Tags: c#, listbox

I have found many answered questions on here explaining how to do this when the objects are created as part of the data source but my list box is just displaying "SharePointXMLBuilder.Farm" (Namespace.class) and not the selected DisplayName?

I dont know what I am doing wrong can anyone help please.

I have a list box with a data source as a databinding control and I am adding my created objects(Farm) to the databinding(farmListBindingSource) which all works fine, I just cant get the list to show the property I want it to.

**Form:** (loads another form takes input and returns to create object from Farm class)

```
private void CreateNewFarm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FarmInput input = new FarmInput();
    input.ShowDialog();

    Farm nFarm = new Farm();
    nFarm.location = input.inputLocation.ToString();
    nFarm.identifier = input.inputType.ToString();
    nFarm.environment = input.inputEnvironment.ToString();

    this.farmListBindingSource.Add(nFarm);

    this.testReturnTextBox.Text = nFarm.friendlyName;
}

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FarmListBox.DisplayMember = "friendlyName";
    this.testReturnTextBox.Text = "Form Loaded....";
}
```

**Class:**

```
namespace SharePointXMLBuilder
{
    class Farm
    {
        private string farmLocation;
        private string farmIdentifier;
        private string farmEnvironment;
        private string farmFriendlyName;
        //private List<Server> farmServers;

        //properties
        public string friendlyName
        {
            get { return farmFriendlyName; }
            set { farmFriendlyName = value; }
        }

        public string location
        {
           get { return farmLocation;}
            set { farmLocation = value; this.buildFriendlyName(); }
        }

        public string identifier
        {
            get { return farmIdentifier; }
            set { farmIdentifier = value; this.buildFriendlyName(); }            
        }

        public string environment
        {
            get { return farmEnvironment;  }
            set { farmEnvironment = value; this.buildFriendlyName(); }
        }

        //constructor
        public Farm()
        {
        }

        //methods
        public void AddServer(string s)
        {
            Server nServer = new Server(s);
            // farmServers.Add(nServer);
        }

        public void buildFriendlyName()
        {
            this.friendlyName = this.location + " " + this.identifier + " " + this.environment;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does, so I know the object has the correct properties, I have tested it with location/identifier/environment and the textbox populates properly but the listbox still remains the same.

Comment: When I override the ToString Method in my class I can get it to display whatever I like but I would have preferred to use the DisplayName property of the list box to decide, is this not possible maybe?

Comment: Code works, so I suspect that you don't have the Load event running.  Try setting the DisplayMember property of the ListBox in the designer.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to manually add DisplayMember in the designer and it wouldn't hold the value, as soon as I removed the DataSource it allowed DisplayMember to be populated so I changed the create to add the object to farmListBox.Items and when I re-ran the code it was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I tried to manually add DisplayMember in the designer and it wouldn't hold the value, as soon as I removed the DataSource it allowed DisplayMember to be populated so I changed the CreateNewFarm_Click to add the object to farmListBox.Items and when I re-ran the code it was fine.

It appears that you cannot use DisplayMember if you are pulling the objects from a DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not calling this function: buildFriendlyName() for each object in the list prior to binding?

Comment: buildFriendlyName() is called within the class every time a property is set, I have tested this in testReturnTextBox and it shows correctly.

Comment: Just for fun, try hard coding a value for that property, like "abc", and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In your buildfriendlyname() method set your private string farmFriendlyName insted of setting the property value friendlyname

Comment: Tried that but no luck.

Comment: Can we see your "FarmInput" Code